How to include SPIRV in a CMake project
SPIRV Cross
How do I include this in my project
I added this to my packages folder
add_subdirectory(SPIRV-Cross)
find_package(spirv_cross_c_shared)
if (spirv_cross_c_shared_FOUND)
        message(STATUS "Found SPIRV-Cross C API! :)")
else()
        message(STATUS "Could not find SPIRV-Cross C API! :(")
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE spirv-cross-c-shared)

iam getting this error
out\build\x64-debug\LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'spirv-cross-c-shared.lib
usually doing this work
add_subdirectory()
target_link_libraries()
but not in this case.
I have added a lot of library to my project but this seems to not work.
also cmake in cmake
1> [CMake] -- SPIRV-Cross: Git hash: fa5ca34+
1> [CMake] SPIRV-Cross:  Testing will be disabled for SPIRV-Cross. Could not find glslang or SPIRV-Tools build under external/. To enable testing, run ./checkout_glslang_spirv_tools.sh and ./build_glslang_spirv_tools.sh first.
1> [CMake] CMake Warning at ExternalLibrary/CMakeLists.txt:85 (find_package):
1> [CMake]   By not providing "Findspirv_cross_c_shared.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
1> [CMake]   project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
1> [CMake]   "spirv_cross_c_shared", but CMake did not find one.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by
1> [CMake]   "spirv_cross_c_shared" with any of the following names:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     spirv_cross_c_sharedConfig.cmake
1> [CMake]     spirv_cross_c_shared-config.cmake
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Add the installation prefix of "spirv_cross_c_shared" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
1> [CMake]   or set "spirv_cross_c_shared_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
1> [CMake]   above files.  If "spirv_cross_c_shared" provides a separate development
1> [CMake]   package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

what is the correct way to add the this

add_subdirectory(SPIRV-Cross)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE spirv-cross-c)

this worked hope this helps my fellow newbies.
